# if-then function returning variable not defined

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I'm trying to create a function where one variable selects whether run a circumference, area or volume function and the second variable is the radius for the selected function. However I keep getting error "c" not defined. I've tried defining the conditions inside and outside of the function `typeSize` with no luck.

```
import math
PI=math.pi

def typeSize(form, radius):
  if form == c:
        def cir(radius):            #circumference of a cirlce
            cCirc=2*PI*radius
            return cCirc
  elif form == a:
        def area(radius):           #area of a cirlce
            aCirc=PI*radius**2
            return aCirc
  elif form == v:
        def vol(radius):            #volume of a circle
          vCirc=4/3*PI*radius**3
          return vCirc

print(typeSize(c, 1))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

c isn't defined in your code, you have to create a variable to use it. I think you meant to put c, a, v in string form:

```
import math
PI=math.pi

def typeSize(form, radius):
  if form == "c":
        def cir(radius):            #circumference of a cirlce
            cCirc=2*PI*radius
            return cCirc
  elif form == "a":
        def area(radius):           #area of a cirlce
            aCirc=PI*radius**2
            return aCirc
  elif form == "v":
        def vol(radius):            #volume of a circle
          vCirc=4/3*PI*radius**3
          return vCirc

print(typeSize("c", 1))
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is that c, a and v are not a variable and were never initialized.
In order to solve the problem c, a, and v should be placed in the `if statement` as string i.e "c", "a", "v".

```py
   if form == "c":
      ...
   elif form == "a":
      ...
   elif form == "v":
      ...
```

And the argument that should be passed to the `typeSize()` method should be string also i.e

```py
   print(typeSize("c", 1))
```

And it will be good programming practise to make use of `class` for this problem.

```py
import math

class Circle:
    """
       Circle(radius)
    """
    PI = math.pi

    def __init__(self, r):
        self.radius = r

    def area(self):
         """ Area of a cirlce
         """
         return (Circle.PI * self.radius**2) 

    def circumference(self):
         """ Circumference of a circle
         """
         return (2 * Circle.PI * self.radius)

    def volume(self):
        """ Volume of a circle
        """
        return 4/3 * Circle.PI * self.radius**3
```

With this `Circle`'s class, you don't need to use `if statement` to get the circumference, area and volume instead you can access them through the method created in the class.
To implement this code,

```
>>>> circle = Circle(3)

>>>> circle.radius
3

>>>> circle.PI
3.141592653589793

>>>> circle.circumference()
18.84955592153876

>>>> circle.area()
28.274333882308138

>>>> circle.volume()
113.09733552923254
```